# PayPal for Android adding products

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am getting started with PayPal SDK for Android  https://www.x.com/developers/ebay
 but I can't understand, where i can specify my products to buy. Like Product1 = 1$, Product2 = 3$, Product3 = 9.99$ etc. Can anyone provide me with this information? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link leads to the ebay developer directory. It appears that you did not do enough research, and that you may not have even found the [correct neighborhood](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-payment-libraries) for mobile development with PayPal products.

The [guide for Android development for PayPal is found here](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf).

You can find a [pizza purchasing application PayPal has offered here](https://github.com/paypalx/tech-talks/blob/master/AndroidDevCamp-March2011/PizzaApp/src/com/paypal/MobilePayments/Pizza/PizzaMain.java). It uses Android's [Spinner object](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) to allow the buyer to choose an item for purchase.

You should expand upon your question so people can answer your question more thoroughly.